# T-SQL DYNAMIC RESULTS INTO UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a unique situation that I cannot seem to find an answer for.  Within SQL, I want to be able to execute dynamic SQL or a stored procedure and turn the results (of which I don't know) into an update statement.

My first thought was to return the results in XML but I am not the author of the SQL or stored procedure so I cannot dictate this.  I couldn't find a way to turn the results into XML for the stored procedure since I cannot edit the procedure itself and I don't know what it is going to return to load it into a table.  So since I don't know the results either will achieve, how can I do this?

Comment: From your question I take, that you miss a lot of information. Now think with my head... I know very little from your question, I do not even know what you want to achieve, nor do I know what result-set you are dealing with, what structure you want to create and - most important! - I do not even know which DBMS you are using (SQL Server, Oracle, ...) Please try to follow this [link: MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: It is SQL SERVER and the issue is that I am trying to accomplish is to try to query the schema or metadata of a dynamic SQL query.  I don't know what is in the query as it is defined by our users ... I want to determine what columns of information are returned so I can take that value and update a table with it.  The only issue I am having is trying to stream results of a dynamic query (which could be inline SQL or executing a stored procedure) into a table or something so I can determine what columns are in it and work with that data.

Comment: I just came back by chance... Your answer passed by, because you did not place a `@Nickname` into it. Without this, there's no alert... Back to the question: If you no **nothing** about the result, if this result might come from a dynamic SQL, a VIEW, a function, a SP it will be hard to find a general approach. You might read about [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (2012+)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258.aspx)

Comment: Has to work in SQL 2008+ so the exec you mentioned isn't an option yet. @Shnugo